# Почему не работает функция в PyCharm для Телеграмм бота?

Tags: python, функции, бот, telegram

Мне надо, чтобы когда пользователь нажимал на 'номер'  он мог текстом ввести номер машины, а бот выводил название машины.
Помогите пожалуйста!

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('Токен')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Поздороваться")
    markup.add(btn1)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет! Я твой бот-помошник!", reply_markup=markup)  
# Тут я думаю всё понятно


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == 'Поздороваться':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Номер')
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Название')
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Все машины')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Я помогу вам найти досье о машине.', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Какую информацию о машине вы знаете?', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == 'Номер':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите гос номер авто', parse_mode='Markdown')
# Следующая функция почему-то игнорируется ботом

        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
        def get_text_messag(messags):

            a = messags.lower()
            if a == 'нффф' or a == '294':
                bot.send_message(messags.from_user.id, '7 серебро', parse_mode='Markdown')
                bot.send_message(messags.from_user.id, 'нффф', parse_mode='Markdown')
                bot.send_message(messags.from_user.id, 'Текст', parse_mode='Markdown')

            elif a == 'аффф' or a == '213':
                bot.send_message(messags.from_user.id, '14 серебро', parse_mode='Markdown')
                bot.send_message(messags.from_user.id, 'аффф', parse_mode='Markdown')
                bot.send_message(messags.from_user.id, 'Текст', parse_mode='Markdown')
# А дальше всё работает

    elif message.text == 'Название':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите название машины', parse_mode='Markdown')

    elif message.text == 'Все машины':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Здесь вы можете увидеть перечинь машин', parse_mode='Markdown')


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: а при чем тут PyCharm?

Comment: у вас полнейший бардак с отступами - это раз, у вас два `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])` - это два

Comment: 1. Больше похоже на aiogram, а не telebot.
2. У вас @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) в @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']), так работать не будет.
3. Вам нужно использовать FSM

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: PyCharm - это я про программу в которой кодирую

Comment: @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) А что здесь надо исправить?
отступы я так делал, потому что так PyCharm ошибку выдаёт если по другому

Comment: И можете пожалуйста хотя бы текстом написать как правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pycharm не имеет отношения к вопросу, это IDE, а не язык программирования.

В остальном, проблема в определениях функции; вы объявляете одну функцию внутри другой.

Попробуйте так:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Поздороваться")
    markup.add(btn1)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет! Я твой бот-помощник!", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == 'Поздороваться':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Номер')
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Название')
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Все машины')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Я помогу вам найти досье о машине.', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Какую информацию о машине вы знаете?', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.text == 'Номер':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите гос номер авто', parse_mode='Markdown')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, handle_car_number_input)

    elif message.text == 'Название':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите название машины', parse_mode='Markdown')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, handle_car_name_input)

    elif message.text == 'Все машины':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Здесь вы можете увидеть перечень машин', parse_mode='Markdown')

def handle_car_number_input(message):
    car_number = message.text
    if car_number == 'нффф' or car_number == '294':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '7 серебро', parse_mode='Markdown')
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'нффф', parse_mode='Markdown')
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Текст', parse_mode='Markdown')

    elif car_number == 'аффф' or car_number == '213':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '14 серебро', parse_mode='Markdown')
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'аффф', parse_mode='Markdown')
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Текст', parse_mode='Markdown')

def handle_car_name_input(message):
    car_name = message.text
    if message.text == 'Название':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите название машины', parse_mode='Markdown')

#### здесь нужно дописать проверку по названию машины, аналогично с предыдущей функцией с номерами машин

def handle_car_name_input(message):
    all_car = message.text
    if message.text == 'Все машины':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Здесь вы можете увидеть перечень машин', parse_mode='Markdown')
#### здесь можете написать логику вывода всех машин. Можете в список все занести и оттуда прогонять, вместо бесконечных if/elif и сделать для всех функции.

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Я бы рекомендовал вместо if/elif проверять по заданному списку элементы на совпадение и дальше уже создать логику вывода информации.
А ещё лучше, если подключите SQL базу данных и через запросы будете работать.

Comment: Если возникнут вопросы, то задавайте их в комментарии. Если данный ответ смог решить Вашу проблему, пожалуйста, поставьте галочку решения, чтобы закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Я прошу прощение, но всё равно бот не переходит на следующую функцию.
И теперь бот реагирует только на 'Номер' а на остальное нет.
А мне надо, чтобы после  нажимании на 'Номер' человек мог ввести 3 цифры, а дальше ему вывело название машины.
Но при нажатии на все машины ему бы вывело перечинь машин

Comment: Можешь пожалуйста комментариями написать?

Comment: Изменил код снова, дополнил немного информации. В этот раз попробовал проверить, всё работает. 
Вам только нужно доработать логику обработки. Я лишь исходил из Вашего исходного кода.

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас попробую

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное. Я даже словами передать не могу как сильно тебе благодарен